# How can i skip after/before destroy callbacks on dependent: :destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I got the scenario where i need to call dependent: :destroy on around 10 child modles. Each child has 5 to 6 destroy call_backs. I need to skip few of them and execute few of them.

How can i achieve same. `delete` and `delete_all` is not feasible.

```
class Parent
   has_many child_a, dependent: :destroy
end

class ChildA
  belong_to : parent
  before_destroy :execute_on_all_destroy
  beofre_destroy :execute_except_dependent_destroy
end
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to determine if a record was destroyed through through the `dependent` option or "normally". You should consider if callbacks are the right answer for what you are doing as the core issue is that its hard to control when they are fired. An alternative is to for example use service objects for creating and destroying the object.

Answer (score 0):

Rails callbacks accepts `:if` and `:unless` to add conditions if the actions should be executed or not: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-symbol

So an option could be to add these conditions to the `ChildA` callbacks:

```
class ChildA
  belong_to : parent
  before_destroy :execute_on_all_destroy, if: :should_destroy_all?
  beofre_destroy :execute_except_dependent_destroy, unless: :should_destroy_all?

  protected

  def should_destroy_all?
    #logic here
  end

end
```

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question as there is no way to determine in the method if destroy was called "directly" on the instance or if it's called through the association.